# Using @ in comments with usernames containing spaces?

Tags: discussion, comments

I guess this is really more of a general meta.stackoverflow question:

Putting @ before a username in comments makes it show up in their inbox. What about if the username contains spaces - does the same thing still work, or are any modifications needed? E.g., if I want to point something out to user "Joe Shmoe", should I use "@Joe Shmoe", "@JoeShmoe", "@Joe_Shmoe", or just "@Joe"?

Comment: You're talking about this guy, right? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/208/joe-shmoe

Comment: @WAF: nah, I just used that as an example. Although that is pretty funny that someone actually took that name...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strip the spaces out.  In your example, you want `@JoeShmoe`.

For more details, the FAQ entry for comment notifications on Meta Stack Overflow is here:  [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/140548)